# SQL return sum of different field values for the same entry

Tags: sql

Could you please help with the following problem:
I have a log table with **id, method, date, status** fields. Typical data row is like so:

> (1, 'GET',  (datetime.date(2016, 7, 2),'200 OK') and (2, 'GET',
>   (datetime.date(2016, 7, 2),'404 NOT FOUND')

How can I write a query that returns a table with the following fields:
**date, sum of '404  Not FOUND', sum of '200 OK'**?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: by sum u mean number?

Comment: which db is this

Comment: @Whencesoever yes I mean the count for that particular response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  date,
  sum(case when status='200 OK' then 1 else 0 end) as sum200,
  sum(case when status='404 NOT FOUND' then 1 else 0 end) as sum400
from the_table t
group by date
```

Use group by date to apply aggregate function for the date groups